# Prevent user from edit a word file when open in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

I have an application that lists multiple Word and Excel files so when the user double clicks on one, it opens and can be edited. I want to give the user permission to edit or not.

I searched a lot and what I came up with so far is

```
ProtectedViewWindows.Open(mFolderPath) 
Process.Start(myDocPath)
```

But it gives me the error:

> Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.

Answer (score 0):

This error message means, that `Open` isn't a shared function in the `ProtectedViewWindows` class, so you have to create a `ProtectedViewWindows` object, before calling `Open` on it.

Something like:

```
Dim pvw As ProtectedViewWindows = New ProtectedViewWindows
pvw.Open(mFolderPath)
Process.Start(myDocPath)
```

Maybe the constructor of `ProtectedViewWindows` expects one or several parameters.

Comment: its give me Error :'New' cannot be used on an interface.

Comment: Then `ProtectedViewWindows` is an interface and not a class. You need to find a class, that implements the interface `ProtectedViewWindows` and create an object of this class instead.

Comment: Are you sure your question has something to do with VB.net? The examples I find on the net seem to refer to VBA instead.

Answer (score 0):

`ProtecfedViewWindow` is not something you're supposed to use to prevent the user from editing the document. This is functionality built into the Office application to open documents from untrusted sources. The explanation in the [Excel language reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/protectedviewwindow-object-excel) is somewhat clearer on this point; you might want to read [What is Protected View](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-protected-view-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653?ocmsassetID=HA010355931&CTT=1&CorrelationId=8fac361c-3912-4838-a022-08f814d06f0a&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), also.

So the answer to your implied question is: You can't do what you want using this part of the object model.

Neither Word nor Excel is designed to function as a "Reader" - they're editors. If you want users to read, only, then you need to look for a Reader. For example, save the files in PDF format so that they open in Acrobat Reader.

FWIW it's possible to protect all or parts of Word and Excel files using their respective protection mechanisms. This has to be applied to the opened files using the object models (or by editing the Open XML of the closed files).

Answer (score 0):

Document object offers Protect method which take Protect Type argument and this Type derived from WdProtectionType enum which has following protection types can consider to prevent editing in a word document: code reference is taken from [Protect document code example](https://vbaoverall.com/protect-a-word-document-using-vba-visual-basic-for-applications/)

- wdAllowOnlyComments
- wdAllowOnlyFormFields
- wdAllowOnlyReading
- wdAllowOnlyRevisions
- wdNoProtection

Following is the code example that you may consider based on protection

```
oDocument.Protect(WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyReading,vbNull,"password")
```

Comment: Your last two answers linked to the same website. While that's not inherently bad, it implies that you might be affiliated with the site in some way. If you are affiliated with the site, then you need to disclose that in the posts in which you link to it. Please see: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).